# Pentaho - Invalid Class Name for S3 Input

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

We're trying out `Pentaho Data Integration ver. 8.0 for Mac (by Hitachi)` for our ETL. I'm trying to hookup an S3 input, have added appropriate S3 access and S3 secret keys, and when I choose `Select Bucket`, I get:

> Request Error: Invalid class name: org.jets3t.service.utils.RestUtils$ConnManagerFactory

Others have also tried it with their working keys and get the same error, so it seems to be a bug with Pentaho and not our keys.

[image]

Comment: Any thoughts here?